# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric - Collation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

```
SELECT HCI.variationID, CAST(isnull(HCI.ContractRef, 0) as numeric(32,2)) as 
targethrs
FROM pcms.Variation_New HCI
```

Quite a simple error but I have tried numerous things without joy. this may help

```
    Column Name   Type          Collation                       
    ContractRef   nvarchar(50)  Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

I need a numeric outcome

Comment: No, that doesn't help. Fix your data first. Use try_cast instead of cast and filter for null values. Those are the one that need fixing.

Comment: I can't change the data type. Your comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Smor mentioned, `try_convert()` or `try_cast()` will not throw an error if the conversion fails... instead it will return a `NULL`.

```
SELECT HCI.variationID
     , isnull( try_convert(numeric(32,2),HCI.ContractRef), 0) as targethrs
FROM pcms.Variation_New HCI
```

The real issue is that you have data that can not be converted.  To identity these records for correction:

```
Select *
 From pcms.Variation_New HCI
 Where try_convert(numeric(32,2),HCI.ContractRef) is null
   and HCI.ContractRef is not null
```

Comment: Thankyou that is more helpful. The TRY_CAST works perfectly.

Comment: @AngArthur Never had a doubt  :)